# Trigonometric calculation, circle within a circle, radius intersection

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Given a circle within a circle, touching sides, calculate where radius y in circle 2 intersects with circle 1.  We know the radii of the circles, the distance between their centers, and the angle of the line y.

Solve for y.

Comment: Is "solve for y" an order for us ?  What have you attempted to do on this homework ? This is a basic principle on Math SE: we are awaiting that the askers explain at least a little what they have done... otherwise, your question can be closed sooner or later.

Comment: No, no "order" for you or anyone.  Just simply a question that I have been trying to solve for days.  Just hoping that someone would kindly explain the solution.  My thanks to M. Yates for the elementary explanation.

Comment: All right. But why didn't you say at first " I was using the law of sines to get all the angles, then the length of y, but I am looking for a simpler solution". It changes all...

Comment: It was my very first question posted in this forum.  I described it as simply and clearly as I could.  I did not want to confuse the issue more by sharing all the calculations that did not work.  Thankfully, someone was willing to answer the question as clearly as it was asked.

Comment: I understand. Don't see any aggressivity in what I have written. But understand this is a forum. On a forum, you need to put flesh on the bare bones of a problem. A reason for that is to make people aware of the level of your attempts. Another is to avoid good-willing people to redo what you have perfectly done or understood. A third reason is that "some" users of this forum use it in the following way "give me quickly the solution, without any effort".

Comment: I wanted an unbiased solution and a fresh look at a problem I have been racking my brain on for weeks (this formula is only one of hundreds).  Had I mentioned the law of sines, you then may have actually answered my question with the correct law of sines process -- and perhaps I would not have learned of the very elegant solution provided by M. Yates.  That was exactly what I was looking for!  When I read a question I can answer, I post my answer as best I can respectfully.  I do not lecture newbies for being newbies.  M. Yates is a fine example to follow.

Comment: Would you please unhold this question -- is is not clear enough yet?  I would like to post the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: I have asked for reopening this question. You have convinced me that you are not an ordinary "learner".

Comment: Is every questioner to be treated as an elementary school child?  If so, then perhaps the simple Ask a Question button should indicate that questions will not be answered unless you prove that you are NOT and 'ordinary' learner?  Very condescending.

Comment: No condescendance on my side : as english is not my mother language, sometimes I do not use the proper terms, I retract the expression "ordinary" Understand that, on the contrary, I wanted to compliment you about your tenacity. I close there.

Answer (score 1):

[Original image with added labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCt4k.png)

Consider the complementary angle to $\theta$ is $\phi=90-\theta$. Then, if $h$ is the distance from the origin to intersection of the smaller circle with the $y$-axis (see attached image), then, from soh-cah-toa, we get: $$h=r_1sin(\phi)$$

Then, consider the triangle formed by $h$, $y$, and a chord of the smaller circle parallel to the $x$-axis (see attached image). Using soh-cah-toa, $cos(\phi)={h\over y} \Rightarrow$ $$y={h\over cos(\phi)} $$

Combining the two equations, we get $y={r_1sin(\phi)\over cos(\phi)}=r_1tan(\phi).$ Thus, $$y=r_1tan(90-\theta) $$

Comment: Thank you!  I was using the law of sines to get all the angles, then the length of y, but this solution is the simplest.

Comment: In your diagram, h is computed as if phi were in a right triangle -- but it isn't.  Don't we have to use the angle between the line from the origin to the intersection and the x-axis?  h would then = r1*sin(that other angle)

Comment: Yes, it does seem I made a mistake...I was using hand drawn drawings initially, so I must've assumed it was a right angle. Sorry about that. Hopefully my answer still gives you some idea of direction to head in!

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the cosine law:
$$
r_1^2=x^2+y^2-2xy\cos\theta
$$
so
$$
y^2-2xy\cos\theta+x^2-r_1^2=0
$$
and so, taking the only positive solution,
$$
y=x\cos\theta+\sqrt{x^2\cos^2\theta-x^2+r_1^2}=
x\cos\theta+\sqrt{r_1^2-x^2\sin^2\theta}
$$
Now you can express this only in terms of $\theta$, $r_1$ and $r_2$ by using the relation $x+r_1=r_2$.

Comment: How did you simplify the equation for y from the 2 equations above?

Comment: @teleman Quadratic formula.